# Making pretty equations in RMarkdown with LaTeX

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm trying to create nicely formatted equations in RMarkdown, but I cannot seem to get it to Knit without errors.  The LaTeX chunk I have looks like this:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "KirkD-CO"
date: "September 18, 2019"
output: pdf_document
---

$$
f(x) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2 + \beta_3 x^3 + \beta_4 (x-\xi)^3_+
\\
\begin{equation}
  (x-\xi)^3_+ =
    \begin{cases}
      (x-\xi)^3 \ , \  x>\xi
      \\
      0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ , \ x\leq\xi
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
\\ 
\
\\
\begin{aligned}
  (x \leq \xi) \Rightarrow f(x) &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2 + \beta_3 x^3
  \\
  (x > \xi) \Rightarrow f(x) &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2 + \beta_3 x^3 + \beta_4(x^3 -3x^2\xi + 3x\xi^2 - \xi^3)
  \\
  &=(\beta_0 + \beta_4\xi^3) + (\beta_1 + 3\beta_4\xi^2)x + (\beta_2 - 3\beta_4)
\end{aligned}
$$
```

And in RStudio I see this:

[image]

But when I try to Knit it, I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
```

I've search Google and StackOverflow and found many similar problems with answers suggesting using [ ] instead of \begin{equation}, other suggest using only one $ instead of $$, and still others refer to a variety of LaTeX packages, a few of which I've tried and wound up in installation purgatory.

Any suggestion on a straight forward way to get Kniter to Knit a PDF with the output RStudio displays?

**EDIT**:  I'm using R 3.5.3 and Kniter 1.22 on Fedora 30.

**EDIT2**:  Under Tools -> Global Options -> Sweave -> Typeset LaTeX into PDF using: is set to pdfLaTeX

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. The LaTeX code compiles fine on R 3.6.1 with `rmarkdown_1.15`.

Comment: Ugh.  What platform are you working on?  I added my software versions and OS to the original post.  I'm using R 3.5.3 and Kniter 1.22 on Fedora 30.

Comment: Try switching `$$ ... $$` to `\[ ... \]`? I think for some compilers that makes a difference. In any case, brackets are "strongly preferred", see, e.g., [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/10371)

Comment: Nope.  The error now is:  
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.97 \textbackslash{}{[} f(x) = \beta
                                     \_0 + \beta\_1 x + \beta\_2 x\^{}2 + 
at the first line

Comment: That sounds like a syntax error then. Do you have unescaped `$` in your text anywhere? Have you tested knitting *only* that equation, or is this in a larger document?

Comment: @KirkD-CO I'm on MacOS Sierra. I've copied only the LaTeX snippet you included, and there's no issues. I agree with Gregor, the issue may be unrelated to the LaTeX code you give. Can you double-check/verify that the bit you included compiles fine?

Comment: I've updated the code snip to the exact code I'm using.  The snip above uses $$...$$ and I've tried \\[...]\\ as suggested in the comments, and I get exactly the same errors I noted.  It has to be a library problem on Fedora.  I'm not sure what to install, though.

Comment: Hmmm, I **can** produce the error, R 3.5.2 on Windows, knitr version 1.21.

Comment: Could this be a `knitr` version issue? I'm on `knitr_1.25`.

Comment: I've isolated the problem to the `cases` section. If I put *anything* after the `\\ ` linebreak inside `cases`, I get the error. If I remove the second line, it compiles. No idea why. I agree with Maurits - perhaps try updating `knitr`. (Perhaps even updating pdfLatex.)

Comment: Ok I can reproduce the error on MacOS, R 3.6.1, `knitr_1.25` with the updated snippet. TBH the LaTeX code looks odd. I'd be surprised if it compiles with `pdfatex`. For example, `begin{equation}` starts math mode, but you are already in (display) math mode because of the `$$`. Next, you shouldn't use all these hard line breaks in LaTeX math mode unless you're using some multi-line math environment (like `cases`, `gather`, `aligned`).

Comment: If I take out the `equation` block, I can get it to compile to pdf, but the formatting is all messed up.  Equations are in the wrong locations, alignment is messed up, the order of the equations is all wrong.  Yipes!  I also upgraded to knitr v1.25 and R 3.6.0 but same problems.  I tried switching to xelatex for the interpreter, but same problems.  I'll work with it a bit more with respect to the `equation` and `cases` blocks and report back.

Comment: @KirkD-CO At least partially the reason for the alignment being off is because you're not using alignment properly. For example, in `cases` you should use `&` to align parts. I have a feeling this is more of an issue with (mis)understanding  LaTeX syntax, than with `rmarkdown`. I'm trying to clean up your LaTeX snippet atm. Will update soon...

Comment: @Mauritis Evers - thank you!  I have no doubt you're right.  My LaTeX is quite poor - obviously.  I removed the `equation` statements and it compiled but everything is on one line that runs of the right edge off the page.

Comment: Hi @KirkD-CO; I've added a example below that should compile without errors. Please take a look.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following up from the comments, here is a cleaned version:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "KirkD-CO"
date: "September 18, 2019"
output: pdf_document
---

$$
f(x) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2 + \beta_3 x^3 + \beta_4 (x-\xi)^3_+
$$

$$
(x-\xi)^3_+ =
\begin{cases}
 (x-\xi)^3\, ,& x>\xi \\
 0  ,& x\leq\xi
 \end{cases}       
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
  (x \leq \xi) \Rightarrow f(x) &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2 + \beta_3 x^3 \\
  (x > \xi) \Rightarrow f(x) &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2 + \beta_3 x^3 + \beta_4(x^3 -3x^2\xi + 3x\xi^2 - \xi^3) \\
  &=(\beta_0 + \beta_4\xi^3) + (\beta_1 + 3\beta_4\xi^2)x + (\beta_2 - 3\beta_4)
\end{aligned}
$$
```

Producing

[image]

Some specific comments:

1. Put separate LaTeX math mode chunks into separate `$$ ... $$` (or `\[ ... \]` environments (unless you use a multi-line math environment, see below).
2. Inside a `cases` environment, use `&` for horizontal alignment of different parts in every case
3. Don't use `\\` unless you're using some multi-line math environment (like `cases`, `aligned`); conversely, if you do use a multi-line math environment, you must separate lines with `\\`.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you for taking the tiime to rewrite my LaTeX and to provide the super-useful comments.  I truly appreciate it!

Comment: You're very welcome @KirkD-CO; learning LaTeX can be a steep learning curve; and then `MathJax` (which renders your LaTeX code in `rmarkdown`) can be a different beast altogether.

Comment: I have much to learn!  If you have suggested resources, in all ears.  

Comment: @KirkD-CO Depends on what your focus is. `rmarkdown`, `LaTeX`, ...?

Comment: Mostly  'rmarkdown' but I need to use LaTeX a lot for situations just like this.  (I just checked your profile and we have very similar backgrounds and research interests.  Small world.)

Comment: As for `rmarkdown`, I found (and continue to find) the ["lessons" on RStudio](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-1.html) very useful. As for `LaTeX`, I'm not sure what the best resource would be, nor whether this is one. In Physics (my original background) most/all written work is done using `LaTeX`, so having to know `LaTeX` kind of comes with the job. I think knowing some basic `LaTeX` can be very useful when moving on to derivatives such as `MathJax`.

Comment: Perhaps also useful is the [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) post on [Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/).